# Moving batch node cause tear

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
manageTiles:(ccTime)dt
{
tiles.position = ccp(tiles.position.x-speed*dt,tiles.position.y);
}
```

I am moving my batch node but it is causing tears, I think its because dt is .3, but how else do i move it based on time without causing tears. The tears are very very small barley noticeable, but still bothers me.

Answer (score 0):

You mean black lines (gaps) between the batched sprites? Tearing is when you draw to the framebuffer while the screen updates.

Two solutions: move the batchnode instead of individual tiles. If the tiles always stay fixed relative to each other that's the fastest solution. Otherwise cast tiles position to int to ensure they're always at pixel locations, otherwise subpixel rendering will cause those gaps. You may also have to cast the batch node's position to int if you use the first solution.

Comment: sorry i didn't show it but tiles is my batch node. So i am moving my batch node and it's still tearing. I tried casting the position to int, now this fixes the tearing, but now its really choppy movement lol. thanks

Comment: @user2121776 casting is basically floor() yeah? Maybe a round() would be smoother? How does TMX do this? they move smoothly without having to do any funny rounding.

Comment: floor but casting is faster.